# Automount parses NIS map incorrectly on SLES 11.2 x86_64

Tags: sles, automount, nis, sles11

Good morning,

I came across a problem in SLES 11.2 x86_64 where the automount daemon parses a NIS map file incorrectly. It seems to be working fine in SLES 11.1 32 bit, and I cannot see any difference in the configurations of the two systems.

What happens:

/etc/auto.master:

```
+auto.nethome
/nethome auto.nethome
```

ypcat -k auto.nethome:

```
roland -hard,intr,noacl,nocto,rw,noatime,nodiratime,rsize=8192,wsize=8192      palermo:/home/san1/roland
...
```

But when I start the autofs, I see the following errors in /var/log/messages:

```
automount[5506]: syntax error in map near [ roland -hard,intr,noacl,nocto,rw,noatime,nodiratime,rsize=8192,wsize=8192     palermo: ]
automount[5506]: syntax error in map near [ home ]
automount[5506]: syntax error in map near [ san1 ]
automount[5506]: syntax error in map near [ roland ]
```

It looks as if the automounter has trouble in parsing the location as host:pathname. As if the slash is rejected by the lexer. As this all is working well on all other nodes (all 32 bit, various Linux flavours, even Solaris), I suspect the problem is at the 64 bit SLES box, rather than with the data.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem is and how to fix?

At the moment I created a local map file by

```
ypcat -k auto.nethome > /etc/auto.local
```

and changed the /etc/auto.master to

```
/nethome /etc/auto.local
```

And that works, but can only be a temporary solution.

Thanks for any advice!

Stefan